# Типы модераторов

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Чем отличаются назначенные модераторы от выбранных?

Одних сама кампания назначила и они всегда будут модераторами, а других сообщество выбрало и они могут быть "уволены"? Или там другая логика?)

Честно долго искал ответ на этот вопрос, но не нашёл обсуждения нигде)) Даже в списке "Похожие вопросы" не увидел что-то похожее))

Comment: @Kromster зачем?

Comment: Это лишнее уточнение не имеет значения для вопроса.

Comment: Модераторы бывают значимые, ссылочные и null.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Если вопрос касается конкретно нашего сообщества, то история такая. Когда только появился ru.stackoverflow (переехал сюда с ХэшКода), потребность в модерации была с первого же дня. Поэтому действовавшим модераторам выбранным еще на ХэшКоде было предложено стать временными назначенными модераторами.
Когда же мы тут все немного обустроились, с временных модераторов "сняли ромбы" и провели [первые выборы сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1).

Связи с "увольнением" тут не прослеживается. Все модераторы условно "пожизненные". Но все могут быть лишены полномочий в случае злоупотреблений/нарушений или по собственному желанию.

Comment: Спасибо за историю!)